# How do I make a breakpoint in Eclipse Neon using GoClipse?

Tags: eclipse, go, breakpoints, eclipse-neon, goclipse

I have a GoClipse project in Eclipse Neon that I am attempting to debug.  On my work computer I am able to create a new breakpoint by clicking on the left side of the code window, but on my home computer this is not working.  Is there somthing that I do not have enabled on my home computer?
How do I make a breakpoint in Eclipse Neon using GoClipse?

Comment: Some possible reasons/tips: maybe you're in a different perspective (e.g Go perspective at work and Java perspective at home), or you opened the Go file with a different editor type (e.g. Go editor vs Java editor), you don't have the necessary tools configured in Eclipse (e.g. Go debugger).

Comment: I have the Go perspective up on both, Both were started via new Go Project and using go files.  GDB is used for debugging both.

Comment: Is the Go editor open on both situations? Is the file part of an Eclipse project, or is somehow an external file?

Comment: Yes, the go editor is open on both and the file is part of an Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you double click on the editor column? Or opened the context menu there? Just a single-click won't work.

[image]